# Finding most probable vector, given angles

Tags: regression, expected-value, regularization

Assuming you have a series of known vectors $k_i$ in $\mathbb{R}^N$, each at an angle $\theta_i$ to a single unknown vector $v$.  All vectors have the same dimension $N$ which can be arbitrarily higher than the number of known vectors.

What is the best way to determine the expected / most probable value for $v$?

Additionally, let's say you have constraints on what $v$ is (std dev., mean, bounds, etc.), what would be the best way to determine a probabilistic value for $v$?

I'm tried pretty much all the `scipy` optimizers, but the results haven't been particularly impressive.   I've also tried to look at this from a purely math perspective, such as the intersection of subspaces, but the notes in this area rarely talk about probability or expected values and I get lost quickly and I am not sure how to approach it.

Comment: I don't fully understand what you're trying to compute - could you add a simple example where the expected value of $v$ can be explicitly calculated? Perhaps taking one or two $k_i$s in 3-dimensions.

Comment: Thanks for replying! In two dimensions it's trivial, right, because $v = R(\theta_i)k_i$ (for any $k_i,\theta_i$),  where $R(\theta_i)$ is the rotation matrix right?  In three dimensions, it starts to get trickier to solve it exactly, and I have no idea on how to do it probabilistically.

Comment: Note I'm not looking for an exact solution or even a set of exact solutions, but rather just the most likely solution / expected value.  It's possible the constraints above (mean, std, etc) might be required.  I'm also looking for a solution in arbitrarily high $N$

Comment: Because the angles give no information about magnitude, you can only hope to estimate the ray determined by $v.$  When $N$ exceeds the number of observations, the problem is underdetermined and there will be a cone of equally valid solutions, determined completely mathematically and described by a sphere within an affine subspace.  (Look at the $N=2$ case, where a single observation gives two solutions corresponding to an $S^0$ in a line.)  There's no such thing as a "probabilistic value" involved here, because you haven't posited any kind of probability model.

Answer (score 2):

**We can convert this into a standard problem and you can go on from there.**  To begin the conversion I will slightly change the notation into a conventional one in statistics.

Let $\beta = (\beta_1,\beta_2,\ldots, \beta_p)^\prime$ be the unknown vector.  You have $n$ observations of the angles $\theta_i$ made between $\beta$ and $n$ known $p$-vectors $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n.$  Because angles give no information about magnitudes, we can only hope to recover $\beta$ up to a positive multiple.  This allows us to assume that, say, $||\beta||=1.$  In that case the inverse cosine of the angle with $x_i = (x_{i1}, x_{i2}, \ldots, x_{ip})$ multiplied by the length $||x_i||$ gives the dot product,

$$y_i = \arccos(\theta_i) ||x_i|| = x_i\cdot \beta = \sum_{j=1}^p x_{ij}\beta_j .$$

Arranging the vectors as rows of a *design matrix* $X$ yields the relation

$$X\beta = y.$$

**This is a standard underdetermined ("$n \ll p$") regression problem,** subject to the constraint $||\beta||=1.$  However, *even this constraint doesn't matter,* because if you find any nonzero solution $\hat\beta$ it still works: remember, we cannot hope to determine $||\beta||$ in the first place.

Various methods exist to estimate $\beta,$ including Bayesian methods, Ridge Regression, and the Lasso.